# Concatenating Video Files using FFMPEG YUV issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libyuv

I am concatenating three videos with FFMPEG.

The 1st and 3rd video of the concatenation were pulled from an AVI file using FFMPEG and converted into MP4.

Their codec information is below.

[image]

The 2nd video in the concatenation is compiled using FFMPEG.  I am compiling frames with FFMPEG to create this video.

Its codec information is below.

[image]
As you can see, the videos share the same codec, resolution and frame rate.

The only thing they don't share is the Decoded format.  One being 4:4:4 and one being 4:2:2

I think I understand what YUV means from this link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

When I concatenate these three videos together, using [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1), it works, but when I try to watch the final video, the video shows the first file playing just right, then the 2nd video in the final video shows up BLANK and the third video plays just fine as well.

So my question is, how do I concat 3 MP4 files, but change what seems to be the decoded format for the 2nd video to 4:2:2.  When I compile the frames, I imagine I can change the YUV format, but I don't know how just yet.

Comment: [Here a link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) that should interest you, if you still need it of course?